# Package babel Error: Unknown option `polish'

Tags: babel

Compiler can't find 'polish' package. - I have no idea what is happening, I was editing the same document a week ago and everything worked perfectly fine. Another error that occurs is "l. 299 \ProcessOptions*". I am quite new to LaTeX so would appreciate your help. (I use TeXworks)

Comment: Do you have the full `babel` package installed? Are you using `\usepackage[polish]{babel}`?

Comment: I do use \usepackage[polish]{babel}. Situation I described above happens only in one document in TeX works (others work fine).

Comment: In this case you should post your document in your question above, otherwise there is not much we do to help you